# How to ignore children count in my SOAP response

Tags: soap, citrus-framework

I am using Citrus Framework 2.8.0 for some integration tests on a SOAP webservice.

For a specific operation, the number of children elements may vary and I currently get this error on some calls:

```
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.TestCaseFailedException: Validation failed: Number of child elements not equal for element 'myResponse', expected '25' but was '21'
```

How should I write my receive() SoapActionBuilder to ignore this count? Or how can I annotate my response template?

```
soap()
    .client(debolClient)
    .receive()
    .payload(new ClassPathResource("templates/responses/myResponse.xml"))
    .schemaValidation(false);
```

Seems that @ignore@ and receive().ignore("/parent/node) won't help.

Answer (score 0):

Template based validation might not be the best way to validate the message in your scenario as it always tries to compare alle elements with all children.

So you might need to switch to something like XPath based validation instead.

You could also use a combination of template based and XPath where you ignore the parent node (where the number of children is of dynamic nature) with `@ignore@` in your template. With additional XPath expressions you could try to validate the dynamic amount of children with XPath.

Also you could switch to a script validation using Groovy or validation callback. This is the most powerful way to validate a message in Citrus where you can code whatever you want to meet the dynamic nature of the messages.